# How to duplicate a mesh within the Blender API

Tags: mesh

I'm wondering how to achieve this operation:
Assuming I have a mesh :

`solid = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=1)`

I need to duplicate it (I want to do some operations on the solid_duplicated.data.vertices)

But as my scene is already full of meshes, I want to select the "solid" mesh before duplicating it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunately, that function just returns `{'FINISHED'}`

```
solid = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=1)
```

thus:

```
import bpy
import mathutils
from mathutils import Vector

# the added object becomes the "active_object", get a reference to it.
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=1)
solid = bpy.context.active_object

# make a duplicate only of the mesh
ico_mesh_dup = solid.data.copy()

# make a new object, and reference the duplicated mesh.
solid_duplicate = bpy.data.objects.new('IcoSphere_duplicate', ico_mesh_dup)

# the object must be added to the scene
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(solid_duplicate)

# prove that the object is created by offsetting its location.
solid_duplicate.location = solid.location + Vector((2,0,0))
```

There's bmesh alternatives, but I think this will work for you.

Comment: thank you, the output of your program was what i expected.

Comment: would you mind also adding the bmesh option?